# How to add counts (by 8) to music

Tags: theory, musicology

I am a salsa instructor and during this quarantine, I am teaching students to dance at their homes via sending them instruction videos, which I make on my own with counts and on music as well.

One area where my students feel the most trouble is, when they have to dance to music. And critically because they are unable to find the "1" in the music.

For that I have am trying to find a piece of software (hopefully on iPhone) where I can add counts to the music. Please help with his. I see videos on YouTube, where there is music and counts are being narrated along. I just want to see, if there is a way of doing that for any piece of music that I want my students to practice on.

Thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because finding software is off-topic. You may be able to get help from the Software Recs SE.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain the original sound quality of the music one of the best ways to do this for an iPhone is to get GarageBand, a free program by Apple. It will allow you to layer audio recordings. There will be a bit of a learning curve but it will be worth it.

The process is first you select and import the song into a track in the program. Then you create a new track for your voice, select the iPhone built in microphone to record with, press record and count through to the end of the song. Listen and individually adjust the levels of each track to your liking. Finally, export or bounce the final product to create a new audio track that has both the music and your voice.